# Cannot get .data of clicked row in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I discovered a strange bug, apparently, I don't know if I did something wrong, anyway:

```
table.on('click', '.edit', function (element) {
    var tr = $(element.target).closest('tr');
    var data = table.row(tr).data();
    this.display(data.id);
}.bind(this));
```

where table is defined in the following way:

```
var table= $('#questions-datatable').DataTable({
```

now this code works when the datatable isn't resized, I mean when I can see all the fields of the row, but when I resize the window and click on the edit button I get:

> Unable to get property 'id' of undefined or null reference

the error appear when the table have this composition:

[image]

as you can see some fields are not visible

this because data is undefined, is that a bug of the library?

TEST ENVIRONMENT: https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/black-dashboard-pro/examples/tables/datatables.net.html

Comment: @mplungjan 'cause I need to access to a function of the instance of the class eg: ClassName.prototype.func_name, in that case is display, anyway is not relevant

Comment: you can check the bug here: https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/black-dashboard-pro/examples/tables/datatables.net.html if you reduce the window dimension the datatable will adapt the width to the screen size and then some fields will disappear, so if you click on the pencil to edit the record you will got the error

Comment: according to this: https://datatables.net/reference/type/DataTables.Api if you use `DataTable()` to create your table, instead of the `dataTable()` (lower case d), you will get a `DataTable` instance, instead of a jquery object. Could the problem be that you are calling jQuery `on` on a `DataTable` object, instead of a `jQuery` one? If you could provide a fiddle, I could check in to this for you.

Comment: @AdamBaranyai I followed the example given by the author of the theme: https://demos.creative-tim.com/marketplace/black-dashboard-pro/examples/tables/datatables.net.html

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
table.on('click', '.edit', function (element) {
    var data = table.row(this).data();
    this.display(data.id);
}.bind(this));
```